# Set the amount of visible bars in the initial plot

Tags: bokeh

I have a barplot using the bokeh library, and I would like to show only the first 5 barplot and then if I want to see the rest of the bars I have to move the x axis to the right or left. I am struggling in find the information that would allow me to do so. 
An example would be this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
import calendar

values = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
days = [calendar.day_name[i-1] for i in range(1,8)]

p = figure(x_range=days,plot_height=500)
p.vbar(x=days, width=0.5, top=values, color = "#ff1200")

output_file('foo.html')
show(p)
```

[image: 1]

and what I would like it would be something like this:

[image: 2]

and then if I want to see the resting of the days I have to click on the figure and move the mouse.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a solution for limiting the x axis while using categorical data. Instead I made a workaround where the x axis labels are overridden by days of the week. This makes it possible to use x_range to limit the x axis.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show

values = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
days = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

p = figure(x_range=(-0.3,4.3),plot_height=500)
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {0:'Monday', 1:'Tuesday', 2:'Wednesday', 3:'Thursday', 4:'Friday', 5:'Saturday', 6:'Sunday'}
p.vbar(x=days, width=0.5, top=values, color = "#ff1200")

output_file('foo.html')
show(p)
```

Comment: Thank you Jasper, your solution does what I want :)